# Readthedocs domain validation status stuck

Tags: read-the-docs

Can't add domain for `readthedocs` project - status stuck on:

```
HTTPS status: pending_validation
```

CNAME pointed to docs.sample.com and `dig` returns `readthedocs.io`. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get alias working on google domains, after 3rd re-add in DNS and another request in `rtd.io`. Still no good on cloudflare tho (no proxy).

UPD guess it some extended delay.